# Differential equation with piecewise coefficient

Tags: differential-equations, piecewise

I have this equation and I need to solve it analytically by Mathematica 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCnxk.png
[image]

I tried the following

```
k = 32;
eqn = {(u^\[Prime]\[Prime])[x] == Piecewise[{{1/2 k^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] k x], 0 <= x < 0.1}, {( k^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] k x])/1.5, 0.1 <= x < 0.2}, {(
  k^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] k x])/0.75, 0.2 <= x < 0.3}, {(
  k^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] k x])/1.5, 0.3 <= x < 0.4}, {(
  k^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] k x])/3.75, 0.4 <= x < 0.5}, {(
  k^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] k x])/0.75, 0.5 <= x < 0.6}, {(
  k^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] k x])/1.25, 0.6 <= x < 0.7}, {(
  k^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] k x])/0.75, 
  0.7 <= x < 0.8}, {1/2 k^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] k x], 
  0.8 <= x < 0.9}, {k^2 Cos[2 \[Pi] k x], 0.9 <= x < 1}}], 
  u[0] == 0.1, u[1] == 0.2}

sol = DSolve[eqn, u[x], x]
```

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I am sorry I am new to this forum so how can I add my code properly

Comment: I added my code

Answer (score 3):

You simply need to enter the `\[Prime]`s without `^`, that means

```
k = 32;
eqn = {(u'')[x] == 
   Rationalize[Piecewise[{{1/2 k^2 Cos[2 π k x], 
      0 <= x < 0.1}, {(k^2 Cos[2 π k x])/1.5, 
      0.1 <= x < 0.2}, {(k^2 Cos[2 π k x])/0.75, 
      0.2 <= x < 0.3}, {(k^2 Cos[2 π k x])/1.5, 
      0.3 <= x < 0.4}, {(k^2 Cos[2 π k x])/3.75, 
      0.4 <= x < 0.5}, {(k^2 Cos[2 π k x])/0.75, 
      0.5 <= x < 0.6}, {(k^2 Cos[2 π k x])/1.25, 
      0.6 <= x < 0.7}, {(k^2 Cos[2 π k x])/0.75, 
      0.7 <= x < 0.8}, {1/2 k^2 Cos[2 π k x], 
      0.8 <= x < 0.9}, {k^2 Cos[2 π k x], 0.9 <= x < 1}}], 
  u[0] == 0.1, u[1] == 0.2}]
sol = DSolve[eqn, u[x], x];

Plot[Evaluate[PiecewiseExpand[u[x] /. sol[[1]]]], {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

`Rationalize` converts this to exact numbers, in order to make it easier for `DSolve`.

Comment: I got this plot but when I solved it using finite element I got a different plot. I compared it to my friend solution by matlab. I found this plot is not the same but the finite element one is correct

Comment: How did you validate that? With these high oscillations, you need quite fine elements in order to reproduce the wiggles with FEM. `D[PiecewiseExpand[u[x] /. sol[[1]]], x, x]` returns the right hand side _exactly_ and satisfies also the boundary conditions.

Comment: I validated it with my friend I used 10000 elements to be fine enough. you are correct I also did that and the solution returns the right hand side

Comment: Ah, now I see it: Your strong formulation is wrong. You have to apply the product rule as $A_1$ is not a constant function: It is piecewise constant, thus its derivative is a linear combinations of Dirac distributions. So you get also term of the form $A_1'(t) \, u'(t) =  -\sum_i \delta_{t_i}(t) \, u'(t)$. You may use `DiracDelta` for formulating this.

Comment: I got your idea but I want to ask what is the value i

Comment: can you help to show how can I mplement on mathematica